# python rename script not working when executed from finder (Mac)

Tags: python

Helly everyone,

I'm kind of new to python, but I have written a little script that helps me rename file extensions.
It's very short, so I'll post it here:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith("gd"):
        os.rename(filename, filename + ".dat")
```

Now, as I have several directories I need to execute this in, it was getting kind of annoying to always navigate to the folder in terminal and execute it from there using the commmand

```
python renamescrip.py
```

Now I stumbled across some advice that would make a python script execute upon double clicking in the Finder, which would make life a lot easier for me, as I would just need to copy and paste the renamescript.py into the folder in which I want to rename the files and double click on it to execute it.

I followed these instructions: http://skillfulness.blogspot.de/2010/12/how-to-run-python-script-from-mac-os-x.html , which show how to create a .command file.

However, when I double clicked the renamescript.command file, it didn't change the file names in the directory.

I also tried opening the .py file with Python Launcher, but that also didn't change the filenames.

Both times a terminal window opened, though, with the message:

```
cd '/path to directory with files to rename/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/path to directory with files to rename/renamescript.py' && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Exit status: 0
logout
```

or if I click on the .command file it's just:

```
/path to directory with files to rename/renamescript.command ; exit;
logout
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if you should use `pythonw`, which is what your messages indicate. Just try and use `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python` instead.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how pythonw turned up there, I can't remember ever setting it as some kind of directory for python and I have absolutely no idea how to change it. I do have a folder /usr/bin/python, but how do I "set" it as default? Sorry if this sounds stupid, but I'm really new to this!

Comment: On the first line of your file put `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: You may also want to `chmod +x renamescrip.py` from the command line, to make this script executable.

Comment: The first line already is "#!/usr/bin/env python" And I also did the part with chmod, exactly as was described in the link I provided above. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you double click, you are not running with the same directory form your current directory as when you run from the shell.  This causes your `os.listdir(".")` to not find the files you think it should.  You should change your directory at the beginning of your script with

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

before your `os.listdir` call

Comment: I changed my code so it is now     `#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

for filename in os.listdir("."):
 if filename.endswith("gd"):
  os.rename(filename, filename + ".dat")` but it's still not renaming the files.

Comment: are you sure the script is being executed?

Comment: I took that script exactly, put it in my home directory in MacOS as `renamescrip.command`.  Made it executable with `chmod`. Made a file also in my home directory called `blahgd`. Ran it from the finder, and it renamed `blahgd` to `blahgd.dat`. You may was to recheck those steps.

Comment: I tried to execute it in my home directory. It worked there for me as well. But as soon as I put the renamescript.command in a different directory, it doesn't work any more. So it somehow can't detect it's current directory, even though I put the `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`bit before the original code.

Comment: Yes, I do have rights. Sorry, it took so long to get back to this but I just got to a part in my work again where I could use this and remembered this thread! Does the script work for you if you put it in any other folder but your home folder? Like somewhere in Documents?

Comment: @freda42 yes, it works everywhere I tried putting it.  in Documents, even off of in `/chicken`.  I make a `sudo mkdir /chicken` dir, then `sudo chmod 777 /chicken`, `mv ~/renamescrip.command /chicken/`, `touch /chicken/blahgd`, then run the `renamescrip.command` from the finder and `blahgd` became `blahgd.dat`.   If you are copying the rename script to a bunch or directories are you sure you are executing the right one?  Can't tell easily from the finder which is which.

Comment: What does the `sudo chmod 777 /chicken` do? Yes, I'm copying the rename script into a bunch of directories. That was the purpose, to make it easier to rename the files without having to navigate through the directories in terminal. That's why I don't know what you mean with "executing the right one". If I make the rename script, turn it into a command, can't I just copy and paste the .command file into any directory and execute it by double clicking it?

Comment: the `chmod` is setting the rights on the directory for owner/groups/everyone.  If you copy the command to the directory, it will execute in that directory.  However if all the copies are all called the same thing.  The finder should find multiple with the same name, all existing in different directories.  Then the question becomes, how do you know which to run.

Comment: I thought the finder knows which to run, because I'm clicking on it... do I have to run chmod on every directory that I copy the command file into?

Comment: @freda42 The finder does know which one to run ... the question was are you clicking the right one.   You only need to `chmod` the directory if you dont have rights to it already.  If it is in a directory created by the same user, then you are probably find.  The way to check is to get a long listing `ls -l` and look at the flags set on that directory.